# Python Program to Find Numbers Divisible by Another Number... unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x

```
list = [1, 3, 6, 24, 64 ,9  ,2]
result =( int (list / 13 == 0) )
print (result)
```

"when i run this code the error comes which is: how to hande it"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/list.py", line 2, in <module>
    result =( int (list / 13 == 0) )
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a loop for access each element:

```
for item in list:
    //Your operation
```

And for discovering if a number is divisible by another you should use module operand *%* and compare to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator to test each element of the list:

```
numbers = [1, 3, 6, 24, 64, 9, 2]
result = tuple(int((x % 13) == 0) for x in numbers)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

**Note:** DO NOT use list as a variable name as it will clobber the `list` built-in.